# save an array in a file

Tags: java, arrays

Write a Java program named storeArray that ask the user for the size of an square array (same number of rows and columns).

Your program should create the array, then fill it with random double numbers in the range of [0.0, 100.0]

After creating the array, your program must save the array in a file named "routes.txt", where the first line is the number of rows, the second line the number of columns, and the data from your array starts in the third line until the end of the file.

my problem is that when i run the program, it does not print the number of rows and columns

```
Random rnd= new Random();
Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("enter the number of row");
                    int rows=input.nextInt();

System.out.println("enter the number of columns");
int columns=input.nextInt();  

double [][] array=new double [rows][columns];

PrintWriter outputFile= new PrintWriter ("D:\\routes.txt");

double min=0.0;
double max=100.0; 
double maxx= (Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1)) + min;

for (int row=0; row<rows ; row++)
    {   System.out.println(array[rows][columns]);
        for (int col=0; col<columns; col++)
        {              
            array[row][col]=maxx;

            System.out.println(array[row][col]);
            outputFile.println(array[row][col]);           
        }            
    }           
outputFile.close();
}
```

Comment: that's because you never coded them to be printed

Comment: and also, you never use `Random rnd= new Random();`

Comment: and also use `print(array[row][col]` and `print(" ")` and at the end `println()` - for a single third line.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like that

```
 outputFile.println("rows = " + rows);
        outputFile.println("columns = " + columns);
        for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
           for (int col = 0; col < columns; col++) {
               array[row][col] = min+(Math.random()*max);
                outputFile.println(array[row][col]);
            }
        }
        outputFile.close();
```

First of all, you should delete that row :

```
Random rnd= new Random();
```

because you've never used it.

Also, changing that

```
double maxx= (Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1)) + min;
```

on my line

```
array[row][col] = min + (Math.random() * max);
```

will get you a random number for each row in your matrix.

Also, if you want to go through your array in main loop like you do

```
System.out.println(array[rows][columns])
```

you will never do that, because, on each row, you still haven't any column, because of that, you can't do that, it would work only in the inner loop like

```
System.out.println(array[row][col]);
```

and it looks like your output into file

Comment: Please, check the answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, I've changed my answer :-)